# Why is my target not skipped on an incompatible platform when building with Bazel?

Tags: rust, cross-platform, bazel

According to https://bazel.build/extending/platforms#skipping-incompatible-targets, targets should be skipped when they aren't compatible with the platform.

I have a minimal reproducible example in Rust below. I would expect `bazel build --platforms=//:qnx-x86_64 //...` to not return an error, since the Rust target is explicitly marked as compatible only with Linux.

Instead what I get is `ERROR: ./hello_world_rust/BUILD:3:12: While resolving toolchains for target //hello_world_rust:hello_world_rust: No matching toolchains found for types @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type, @rules_rust//rust:toolchain_type.`

I use bazelisk with Bazel version 6.1.0. The host OS is Ubuntu.

**./BUILD**

```py
platform(
    name = "qnx-x86_64",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:qnx",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

**./WORKSPACE**

```py
load("//:repositories.bzl", "load_bazel_skylib_repositories", "load_rules_rust_repositories")
load_bazel_skylib_repositories()
load_rules_rust_repositories()
load("//:setup.bzl", "setup_rules_rust_repositories")
setup_rules_rust_repositories()
```

**./hello_world_rust/BUILD**

```py
load("@rules_rust//rust:defs.bzl", "rust_binary")

rust_binary(
    name = "hello_world_rust",
    srcs = ["src/main.rs"],
    edition = "2021",
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
)
```

**./hello_world_rust/Cargo.lock**

(skipped)

**./hello_world_rust/Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "hello_world_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
```

**./hello_world_rust/src/main.rs**

```rust
fn main() { println!("Hello, World!"); }
```

**./repositories.bzl**

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:utils.bzl", "maybe")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

VERSION = "1.3.0"
def load_bazel_skylib_repositories():
    maybe(
        name = "bazel_skylib",
        repo_rule = http_archive,
        urls = [
            "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/{version}/bazel-skylib-{version}.tar.gz".format(version = VERSION),
            "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/{version}/bazel-skylib-{version}.tar.gz".format(version = VERSION),
        ],
        sha256 = "74d544d96f4a5bb630d465ca8bbcfe231e3594e5aae57e1edbf17a6eb3ca2506",
    )

RULES_RUST_VERSION = "0.18.0"
def load_rules_rust_repositories():
    maybe(
        name = "rules_rust",
        repo_rule = http_archive,
        sha256 = "2466e5b2514772e84f9009010797b9cd4b51c1e6445bbd5b5e24848d90e6fb2e",
        urls = [
            "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/releases/download/{version}/rules_rust-v{version}.tar.gz".format(version = RULES_RUST_VERSION),
            "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/releases/download/{version}/rules_rust-v{version}.tar.gz".format(version = RULES_RUST_VERSION),
        ],
    )
```

**./setup.bzl**

```py
load(
    "@rules_rust//rust:repositories.bzl",
    "rules_rust_dependencies",
    "rust_register_toolchains",
    "rust_repositories",
)

def setup_rules_rust_repositories():
    rules_rust_dependencies()
    rust_repositories()
    rust_register_toolchains(versions = ["1.61.0"], edition = "2021")
```

Comment: Random guess: Take a look at the implementation of `rust_binary`- maybe the attribute `target_compatible_with`is simply not forwarded...